# Why is the year in this ISO timestamp not 2019?

Tags: amazon-web-services, time, date

For a simple app I'm using to test a devops pipeline I'm outputting the start time of a build to the homepage. On my development machine the year of the ISO-8601 timestamp I expect, 2019, is printed (specifically, "2019-09-12T20:11:00.000Z"). When the same codebase is built using AWS CodeBuild the ISO-8601 timestamp looks like "+051668-02-09T08:09:32.000Z". What is "+051668"? I presume it's the year; My best guess is it's the year represented as a different calendar. Thoughts?

AWS CodeBuild sets this environment variable for every build (CODEBUILD_START_TIME). I'm building with their latest, default, Ubuntu container (v2.0).

Comment: @AuxTaco wow, guess this is wrong/incomplete then? https://i.imgur.com/LgnmacQ.png , deleted my comment

Comment: @hanshenrik That grammar doesn't appear to allow for five-digit years at all. I hesitate to say it's *wrong*, since expanded years are "only allowed by mutual agreement of the partners in information interchange."

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Most of the google hits show CODEBUILD_START_TIME being represented as the number of milliseconds since 1970.  I suspect somewhere in your code you are treating that as if it were seconds.

If you convert `+051668-02-09T08:09:32.000Z` to seconds you get `1568320819772`.  If you divide+round that by 1000 you get `1568320819` then convert that back to a human readable time you get `September 12, 2019 8:40:19`.

Comment: Yep, test data was a unix timestamp in seconds! Thought I had grabbed that timestamp directly from CodeBuild logs, but guess not.

Comment: Bad docs too; Amazon just says "the start time of the build" 

Comment: Provided some feedback for the docs to be more specific about the timestamp via the link in the bottom right https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html .